# How to combine date field and time field to store in datetime field in Django api post request?

Tags: django

I am Posting date and time separately and trying to save it in my Django datetime field. Here is my code:

views.py

```
event = Event()
start_date = request.POST['start_date']
start_time = request.POST['start_time']
event.start_timestamp = datetime.combine(start_date,start_time)
event.save()
```

Comment: i am getting error combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not str when i post start_date = 2019-06-11 and start_time = 06:11

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```py
start_date = request.POST['start_date']
start_time = request.POST['start_time']
start_timestamp = datetime.strptime(f'{start_date} {start_time}', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```